# Db2: I want to union two queries but getting error

Tags: db2

I have this query:

```
select DISTINCT SUBSTR (A.RECORD_KEY,1,10) AS "PRODUCER_TAX_ID",     
CASE WHEN A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD IN ('LOBD', 'LARD') THEN '' ELSE 
SUBSTR (A.RECORD_AREA,29,8) END AS "APPOINTMENT_EFFECTIVE_DATE"    
from PPL_S01.REG A, PPL_S01.MPR B       

UNION 

select DISTINCT SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10) AS "PRODUCER_TAX_ID",
 C.APPT_LOB_EFF_DT AS "APPOINTMENT_EFFECTIVE_DATE" 
from PPL_S01.REG A, PPL_S01.MPR B, PPL_S01.APPTLOB C
```

It gives this error:

> Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=4.12.79`

Why?

Comment: Are there really spaces in `A. RECORD_KEY`and `A. RECORD_AREA`?

Comment: no there is no spaces

Comment: if `C.APPT_LOB_EFF_DT` is a numeric column, try with `char(C.APPT_LOB_EFF_DT)` or `THEN NULL` when `A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD IN ('LOBD', 'LARD')`

Comment: As you are using a very old jdbc driver, (looks like a special build of dating from the year 2010, which has been unsupported since 2017), you will get symptoms like this , when using antique drivers with currently shipping Db2 server versions.  It is wise to __keep your jdbc drivers updated__ on all your clients when you upgrade you Db2-servers.

Comment: select DISTINCT SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10) AS "PRODUCER_TAX_ID",
CASE WHEN B.SEX_CODE = 'E'THEN TRIM(B.CORPORATE_NAME) ELSE TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME) || TRIM(B.MIDDLE_NAME) || TRIM(B.LAST_NAME) END AS "PRODUCER_NAME", SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,11,2) AS "STATE_CODE", CHAR(C.APPT_LOB_EFF_DT) AS "APPOINTMENT_EFFECTIVE_DATE",
A.ORIGINATOR_CD AS "USER_ID",
CASE A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD WHEN 'LOBA' THEN 'ADD' WHEN 'LOBC' THEN 'UPDATE' END AS "TRANSACTION_TYPE",
C.ELECTRONIC_PROC_IND AS "SEND_TO_STATE", A.LOG_DT_R AS "LAST_CHANGED_DT" , NULL AS "TIME_PROCESSED"

Comment: from PPL_S01.REG A, PPL_S01.MPR B, PPL_S01.APPTLOB C
where A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD IN ('LOBA','LOBC')
AND B.MSTR_AGENT_ID = SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10)
AND B.MSTR_AGENT_ID = C.MSTR_AGENT_ID
AND C.MSTR_AGENT_ID = SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10)
AND C.STATE_CODE = SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,11,2)
AND NOT (C.MSTR_AGENT_ID = SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10) AND A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD = 'LARA')

Comment: "I am getting one add only if I add a policy then delete then add in the same day I am only getting one add and one delete"